# Hive dynamic partition in insert overwrite from select statement is not loading the data for the dynamic partition

Tags: hive, hiveql

Hive dynamic partition in insert overwrite from select statement is not loading the data for the dynamic partition instead it gives the data **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**.

If I say show partitions table2;

it just give only one partition detail which is **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

I have a staging table without any partitions which reads data from a sequence file.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1(DS string, col1 string, col2 string, col3 string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
LOCATION '/user/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

The date format is m/d/yy for the field DS which is coming from the file.

Then I am creating production table like below.

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2(col1 string, col2 string, col3 string)
PARTITIONED BY (DS string)
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

Then the insert query as below

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2 PARTITION (DS)
SELECT col1, col2,col3, cast(DS as date)
FROM table1;

When I query the table 2 I get the result as below

d1 d2 d3 **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**
d4 d5 d5 **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

for the last column where I expect a date field from my partition column instead I get **HIVE_DEFAULT_PARTITION**

My expected data is like

d1 d2 d3 5/1/17
d4 d5 d5 5/1/17

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

The only format you can cast directly to date is `yyyy-mm-dd` any attempt to cast from another format results in NULL, therefore all your records go to the default partition.

- Define the partition column as DATE (`PARTITIONED BY (DS date)`)
- Use  `to_date(from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp(DS,'M/d/y')))` for conversion

#### Demo

```
hive> select cast('5/1/17' as date) as ds;
OK
ds
NULL
```

---

```
hive> select cast('2015-05-01' as date) as ds;
OK
ds
2015-05-01
```

---

```
hive> select to_date(from_unixtime(to_unix_timestamp('5/1/17','M/d/y'))) as ds;
OK
ds
2017-05-01
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to have partition like you mention, As partition can be made on any  field so value format could be differ.

Comment: I did not underdtsnd the question